# Are some hacking timelines more advantageous than others?

Tags: ingress

When hacking a portal and total time on scene is not the first concern, is there a strategy for timing hacks to receive better/more items or extend the life of the portal? Does hacking it 3 times back-to-back as fast as it cools off work better, or would giving it 10 or 15 minutes between hacks let you get more goods if you had an hour or so to stay at it?

Also, does leaving the scene and returning later have a different effect than staying in range for the same period of time between hacks?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, nothing you mentioned has an effect on a portal.

- Minimum time between two portal hacks: 5 minutes
- Portal burn-out after 4 successful hacks
- Portal hackable again 4 hours after first successful hacking
- Only two things influence what items are dropped:

  - Own/enemy portal = more/less items
  - Portal level x => Items dropped with level x-2 to x+2

Example 1:

- Hack 1: 0:00h
- Hack 2: 0:05h
- Hack 3: 0:10h
- Hack 4: 0:15h
- Portal recovered at 4:00h

Example 2:

- Hack 1: 0:00h
- Hack 2: 3:45h
- Hack 3: 3:40h
- Hack 4: 3:55h
- Portal recovered at 4:00h

So if you have 15 (+ x) minutes, hack the portal 4 times and then leave, as there is nothing else to do for the next 4 hours.

Source: 
http://ingressfieldguide.com/content/faq

Comment: Are there any information about own/enemy portal hacking? I have seen that i get much more portal keys from enemy portal hacking.

Comment: @Bomberlt From what I've experienced, enemy or friendly doesn't matter for portal keys or shields. For the rest it does.

Comment: One thing to consider about the burnout: if you know you have time to spend hacking a portal at a specific time, if you have a chance to hack it once a bit less than 4h before, you can have the burnout reset happen while you're there. For example, if you know you can hack a portal at 17:00 and stay there a while, and you can hack it at 13:20, you can hack it again at 17:00 when you come back, then 17:05, then 17:10, then you're burned out but at 17:20 it resets so you can have 4 more hacks at 17:20, 17:25, 17:30 and 17:35. Also useful when attending planned farming sessions.

Answer (score 0):

As far as is known, the results of a hack depend **only** on the portal level, your level as determined by your APs, the portal status (friendly, enemy, or netural), and random chance.